# I have 18 rows in my table and table has added into panel but I want to display maximum 10 rows rest should be scrollable

Tags: java, swing

I have 18 rows in my table and table has added into panel but I want to display maximum 10 rows rest should be scrollable.
Some code that I have tried:

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with your code.

Comment: 1) Don't post images of text, post the text as an [edit] to the question. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to fill the table.

Comment: You will need to look at the [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface. I'd recommend having a look at how `JTable` implements it.  Using this, you can also use the `rowHeight` property of the `JTable` to calculate the preferred viewport height - but this all just guess work

Comment: Actually, I just noticed the image(1) actually shows almost an MRE / SSCCE (less the import statements).  1) There is an image URL seen only in edit mode, it shows neatly formatted code.

Comment: @theduck **Do *not*** edit images of text into questions. It only encourages people to keep doing what they should never have done.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display maximum 10 rows rest should be scrollable

1. Well you would start by passing 10 as a parameter to your method. Not 5.
2. The size of the table includes the size of the table header.

So your height calculation also needs to include:

```
height += table.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize().height;
```

3. Don't set the maximum size of the panel. The size of the panel will be determined by the preferred size of the component added to the panel. If you don't want the panel to grow as the frame is stretched, then don't use a panel with a BoxLayout.

Just add the scroll panel directly to the frame using:

```
jfrm.add(jsp, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

4. Don't set the size of the frame. That is the job of the `pack()` method to set the frame size based on the preferred size of the components added to the frame.